# is it possible to read symlink value without copying argument string?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

The Linux system call `readlink` to read a symbolic link has the prototype:

```
ssize_t readlink(const char *pathname, char *buf, size_t bufsiz);
```

In common usage, when one writes a function to access a file path given by a constant null-terminated string, the directories in the path may be symlinks which have to be followed first, to get to the file.  See for example the prototype for the function `open`:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
```

While the path is null-terminated, the directories in it are terminated by `/` and one has to supply them as arguments to `readlink`.  Because the path characters are "read-only", one cannot, even temporarily, replace the `/` characters with 0.

That means one has to copy the directories first, append a 0, and then apply `readlink`.  This is slower compared to temporarily replacing one character.

It seems strange to me that all existing Linux libraries would have to do this and there would be no way to do this faster.

I need to write a function to access file paths as fast as possible.  Is there no other way to follow directory symlinks, than to copy the directory strings to apply to `readlink`?

Added: an example - let's say I wanted to write the function `open`.  This function, has to traverse the path given to it, each time when it sees a directory, it has to see if that is a symlink, and if so, read it and follow it.

Comment: It would help if you show us some actual or pseudo-code which shows precisely what operations you are performing.  I'm not completely sure what you're trying to accomplish vis a vis following symlinks and opening files.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, unless you explicitely pass `O_NOFOLLOW` or `O_EXCL` to `open`, `open` *will* follow symlinks. There's no such thing as having 'to follow symlinks first'.

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt yes but my question is not about the usage a call such as `open`, my question is about _writing_ such a call

Comment: @JohnZwinck OK I added the clarifying example at end

Comment: @MarkGaleck, in that case, it's done once, in the kernel, not all libraries have to do that.

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt so if I wanted to write a function such as `open` but in userspace then I have to do this expensive copy operation?

Comment: This dates back well before Linux, by the way - and the pathname is copied from user space to kernel space in UN\*X kernels, including but not limited to Linux, so there's no extra cost in systems with in-kernel implementations of `open()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to implement a function similar to:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
```

You have decided to follow symlinks at every level of the path using this:

```
ssize_t readlink(const char *pathname, char *buf, size_t bufsiz);
```

And you want to avoid copying `pathname` yet still be able to pass prefixes of it to `readlink()`.

I dug into the source code for `readlink()` hoping to find that we could easily modify a clone of it for your purposes.  My idea was that perhaps there was an underlying function which could be given an explicit length for `pathname` rather than relying on the null terminator.

But I had no such luck.  For example: https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.23/sysdeps_2unix_2sysv_2linux_2generic_2readlink_8c_source.html

Since null-terminated strings are the *lingua franca* in C, you may be somewhat out of luck.  The best suggestions I can give you are:

1. Change your `open()`-alike to take `pathname` as non-const.  This may force some callers to copy the argument, but at least those who already hold a non-const string can use it directly.
2. Use a pool (one per thread really, so consider using thread-local storage) of preallocated strings of length `PATH_MAX` in your `open()`-alike.  Copying strings when the target is already allocated is not so slow, and you only need to do it once per `open()` (after which you can swap `/` for `'\0'` as noted in your question.
3. Use [`realpath()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath) instead of `readlink()`.  It canonicalizes an entire path at once, so perhaps you don't need to worry about copying apart from the single copy made inside `realpath()` itself (which you'd also suffer with `readlink()`).

Comment: @JonnZwinck  yes exactly, thank you I appreciate you doing this, I did not intend that you would have to "dig into source", I was hoping someone would already _know_ if there was such a "underlying" call, that uses "length" argument

Comment: I cannot change the prototype of my open-alike to use non-const.  I wish I could...  your answer is very relevant, it seems I am indeed out of luck

Comment: @MarkGaleck: You're welcome. I added a third alternative, `realpath()`, which you might find useful.

Comment: yes  I know about `realpath` but I can't - and in any case, `realpath` also has to copy